# AWS EC2: req.cookies["jwt_auth"] is undefined

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, jwt

The frontend of my website is deployed at https://******.netlify.app
The backend of my website is deployed on AWS EC2 using cadddy and nip.io. The root directory contains my source code folder and a Caddyfile. I ran the command `sudo caddy start` to run caddy in the background. The Caddyfile looks like the following:
(IP address hidden)

```
IP.IP.IP.IP.nip.io {
    reverse_proxy localhost:5000
}
```

Which means my backend server runs on https://IP.IP.IP.IP.nip.io

I am using Google OAuth using Passport.js and my routes look like the following:

```
router.get(
  "/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile", "email"],
    prompt: "select_account",
  })
);
router.get(
  "/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failWithError: true, session: false }),
  AuthController.handleAuthentication
);
```

The handleAuthentication function is as follows:

```
// config is imported somewhere above (not shown for conciseness)
const handleAuthentication = async (req, res) => {
  const user = req.user;
  try {

    // Generate our own token from our google user
    const token = generateToken({
      id: user._id.toHexString(),
      secret: config.JWT_SECRET,
      errorMessage: null,
    });

    return res
      .cookie("jwt_auth", token, {
        maxAge: config.SESSION_DURATION * 60 * 1000,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      })
      .redirect(`${config.CLIENT_URL}/home`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

The user is successfully redirected to `${config.CLIENT_URL}/home` after logging in.
I have a middleware function which is called when any API call is made:

```
const ensureAuthWithSubscription = (minimumPlan) => {
  return async function (req, res, next) {
    // Get the cookie for authorization
    // In this case, cookie name is jwt_auth
    const cookie = req.cookies["jwt_auth"];

    // Extract the id from the token saved in the cookies
    const id = verifyToken({
      token: cookie,
      secret: config.JWT_SECRET,
      errorMessage: null,
    });

    // Check if there exists a user with the given id
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    if (!cookie) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: `Cookie not found while checking auth and sub! cookie: ${cookie}, id: ${id}`,
      });
    } else if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: `User not authorized while checking auth and sub! user: ${user}`,
      });
    }
    // code below not shown for conciseness
```

The console is my client app (right click -> inspect -> console) shows the error "Cookie not found while checking auth and sub! cookie: undefined, id: undefined"

I am certain this string is being returned from the `ensureAuthWithSubscription` since no where else in my code is this string mentioned.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. More than happy to set up a zoom call or pay someone to help me with this.

I tried changing the Caddyfile to the following (didn't work, same error):

```
13.58.8.10.nip.io {
    reverse_proxy localhost:5000 {
        header_up Cookie {http.request.header.Cookie}
    }
}
```

The following Caddyfile didn't work either:

```
13.58.8.10.nip.io {
    reverse_proxy localhost:5000 {
        header_up Cookie {http.request.header.Cookie} {preserve}
    }
}
```

The jwt authentication works in my local dev setup, but not in prod which makes me thing the problem is with the reverse_proxy and that the cookies aren't being forwarded properly (not sure about this, it's just my suspicion). (Also if someone knows how to view console.log statements in this setup please let me know. Or if there's a logging library to aid in such debugging).